# Existence of bounded continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I'm struggling to prove or disprove the existence of continuous functions

1. $f : [0,1] \rightarrow [0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q} $
2. $f : [0,1]  \cap \mathbb{Q} \rightarrow [0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q} $
3. $f : \{0,1\} \rightarrow \{0,1\}$

where $f(0)=1$ and $f(1)=0$.
I have a vague idea that 1. and 3. can exist (for 1. it may have something to do with $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ and for 3. since both the definition and value ranges are in $\mathbb{N}$). I'm not sure about 2. Any guidance or suggestion is very much appreciated.

Comment: 1 can't exist. Take any $y \in (0, 1) \setminus \mathbb{Q}$. Apply the IVT to see that $y$ is attained.

Comment: *hint for 1*: Can a continuous function map an interval to a disconnected set?
For 2 and 3, I'm not sure what topology we're working with

Comment: 2 is very easy. Choose an affine function with $f(0) = 1$ and $f(1) = 0$.

Comment: 3 is even easier. There is only one possible candidate $f$. You can prove that it is continuous. $\delta = \frac{1}{2}$ always works.

Comment: I'm not so sure about your comment regarding 2. Can you explain a bit more @Meowdog?

Answer (score 1):

1. Assume such function $f$ exists. Then choose $y \in (0, 1) \setminus \mathbb{Q}$, i.e. $0 < y < 1$. Then, since $f(0) = 1 > f(1) = 0$, according to the intermediate value theorem, there exists some $x \in [0, 1]$ such that $f(x) = y$. That is a contradiction since $y \notin [0, 1] \cap \mathbb{Q}$.
2. Choose $f(x) = -x+1$. Let $\varepsilon > 0$ and $x \in [0, 1] \cap \mathbb{Q}$. Choose $\delta 0 \varepsilon$. Then for all $y \in [0, 1] \cap \mathbb{Q}$ for $\lvert x - y \rvert < \delta$:
   $$
   \lvert f(x) - f(y) \rvert = \lvert x - y \rvert < \delta = \varepsilon
   $$
   So $f$ is continuous, i.e. such function exists.
3. Choose $f(x) = -x+1$ again.